# Can't get absolute positioning to work in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

In IE8 my image, using an absolute position, is shifted up a few more pixels than it should be.  It looks fine in Firefox/Chrome/IE8Compatibility.  I've looked at various threads about this topic and can't get anything to work.  Here is what the code looks like:

```
<a href='/'><img src='/' border='0' width='180' height='40' style='position:absolute; margin-left:90px; top:0px;'></a>
```

This puts the image at the top of the page and it shows fine in all browsers except IE8 unless in compatibility mode.  I have the doc type at the beginning:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Using any other doc type seems to break my page.  I tried setting it to force compatibility in IE but then the flash on my page doesn't load.

Anything else I can try?  Thanks.

Comment: Please define what is wrong in IE8. You just say it doesn't work the way you want.

Comment: I edited my post.  Hopefully it's a bit more clear.  My image is being moved a few pixels above where it should be in IE8 but not in any other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that you are going to have to put your style="position: absolute;" inside your <a> tag.

Try using a css reset snippet which fixes many incompatibility issues with IE.

Comment: What do you mean by "inside your tag"?  It is currently in the image tag.

Comment: Moving it to the <a> tag did not solve the issue either.  I also have another image without a href, an input form, and a flash slideshow that it does the same thing to.  I would just force IE7 compatibility but for some reason my flash slideshow doesn't work when I do that.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Edit for my first response.  Flash does show up in IE7 compatibility but it's placement is way off the screen.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/mrc5e  The top is Firefox and the bottom is IE8.  It moves my body down a bit (I think because the image moved up).  The search has been moved up a little bit in IE and so has the picture on the right.  They all use the same coding except different locations.

Comment: Have you tried the CSS reset? It seems like your problem is padding in the html element. in your css put html {padding:0; margin:0;}

Comment: I tried adding html {padding:0; margin:0;} to the CSS and that did not change anything.  For a CSS reset do you just paste that code in at the front of your CSS?  I tried that and it didn't change anything either.  Or are you supposed to start your CSS from scratch with that code?  My webpage was built off a template so I didn't do most of the CSS.  Anything else I could try?  Thank you very much for continuing to help me.

Comment: Finally found what was causing it.  When I comment out <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/includes/flashgallery/swfobject.js" ></script>  from my page it makes the white space go away.  So I will just need to try and find something in there to change.  The flash gallery is located here: http://www.flash-gallery.org/